# Is there a way to login to a website that listens for javascript in python? (Without Selenium)

Tags: python

I can log into a website partially, but to open a popup the browser listens for "(".googleplus-login").click()", and I dont know how to submit that to the site. If I type that command into the browser console it opens, so I essentially want to do that, but with python. Im kinda looking for something like mechanicalsoup but something that can send javascript.

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open("https://accounts.veracross.com/pa/portals/login")

print(browser.get_url())

browser.select_form('form[action="/pa/portals/login/user_lookup"]')
browser["username"] = "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"
#browser["password"] = "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"

browser.submit_selected()

print(browser.get_url())
"""
browser.follow_link("#")
browser.get_current_form()
"""
form = browser.select_form()

form.print_summary()

#(".googleplus-login").click(function(o){e(!0),o.preventDefault(),gapi.auth.authorize({response_type:"code",cookie_policy:"single_host_origin",client_id:n,prompt:"consent",scope:"email",access_type:"online"}

#$(".googleplus-login").click() THIS NEEDS TO BE SUBMITED
```

Comment: You should research what `.click()` uses for the HTTP _method_; i.e. is it a GET request? From there, you can use any of the HTTP packages for Python

Comment: Also my guess is that you’ll need to carefully consider what HTTP headers to use. If you used your browser the fetch the original page, the server you are trying to reach will probably get confused if your `user-agent` header changes for the request you need to make.

Comment: @will_f Nothing gets sent when the button is clicked, and I'm pretty sure that the process is loaded earlier.